# Inserting item in string after specific word

Tags: python

I want to write a function that takes a string, finds the tsp or tbsp format, and converts that to gram.

Then, I store this information in c and have to insert it behind the tbsp/tsp word in the string. Since strings are immutable I was thinking of converting it to a list first, but now I am a bit stuck.

Anyone has advice on how to do this? :)

Examples:

```
 input                   output
```

> "2 tbsp of butter"    -->  "2 tbsp (30g) of butter"
>
> "1/2 tbsp of oregano" -->  "1/2 tbsp (8g) of oregano"
>
> "1/2 tsp of salt"     -->  "1/2 tbsp (3g) of salt"

```
def convert_recipe(recipe):

    c = ''

    for i in recipe: # save the digit
        if i.isdigit():
            c += i
    if 'tsp' in recipe: # convert tsp to gram
        c = int(c) * 5
    elif 'tbsp' in recipe: # convert tbsp to gram
        c = int(c) * 15

    # now we have c. Insert (c) behind tsp / tbsp in string    


recipe = recipe.split()
print(recipe)
convert_recipe("2 tbsp of butter")
```

Comment: if "1/2 tbsp" is once (8g), once (3g) and "2 tbsp" are (30g), something is seriously wrong with *tbsp-math*.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis "Given all the measures in tablespoon (tbsp) and in teaspoon (tsp), considering 1 tbsp = 15g and 1 tsp = 5g, append to the end of the measurement the biggest equivalent integer (rounding up)"

Comment: Could have added that to the question; it would have saved much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that should cover most cases.

```
from fractions import Fraction
from math import ceil

def convert_recipe(recipe): 
    weight = {'tbsp': 15, 'tsp': 5}  # store the weights for tsp and tbsp
    ts = 'tbsp' if 'tbsp' in recipe else 'tsp'
    temp = recipe.split()            # convert string to list
    quantity = float(Fraction(temp[temp.index(ts)-1]))
    new_recipe = recipe.replace(ts, '{} ({}g)'.format(ts, ceil(quantity*weight[ts])))  # see (1)
    return new_recipe


print(convert_recipe("2 tbsp of butter"))   # -> 2 tbsp (30g) of butter
print(convert_recipe("1/2 tbsp of butter")) # -> 1/2 tbsp (8g) of butter
print(convert_recipe("1/2 tsp of salt"))    # -> 1/2 tsp (3g) of salt
```

---

(1): here are are actually replacing the `'tbsp'` part of the sentence with `'tbsp (30g)'` for example. The string that is inserted (`'tbsp (30g)'`) is a result of *string formating*.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Could you ellaborate on this part -->  recipe.replace(ts, '{} ({}g)'.format(ts, ceil(quantity*weigt[ts]))) or a resource where I could read about it?

Comment: Oh and this part as well : float(Fraction(temp[temp.index(ts)-1]))

Comment: I don't know why but this sentence does not return the right answer. "Add to the mixing bowl and coat well with 1 tbsp of olive oil & 1/2 tbsp of dried dill"),  -- should be     "Add to the mixing bowl and coat well with 1 tbsp (15g) of olive oil & 1/2 tbsp (8g) of dried dill"

Comment: @Daphne because multiple instances are not supported. The `quantity` is defined by the first occurrence. The examples provided in the question and the question body did not hint towards such a use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'tsp' in recipe:                  (1)
    c = int(c) * 5
    recipe = recipe.split('tsp')     (2)
    recipe = recipe[0] + 'tsp (' + str(c) + 'g)' + recipe[1]
```

// similar code for tbsp

I believe this will work for you?

Edit:

at (1), recipe = "1/2 tsp of salt"

at (2), recipe becomes ["1/2 ", " of salt"]

And then its all about adding the strings back together

The split method splits the string based on the given argument and returns an array of strings

Comment: It works! thank you. Could you describe what happens when you do recipe.split('tsp') ?

Comment: how does this deal with Fractions?

Comment: I haven't changed the logic behind calculating `c`.

Comment: @NannanAV There was no logic behind the calculation of `c` (`c = ''`)

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by "How does this deal with Fractions?"